# x86 CPUID feature flags in chronological order

Tags: cpuid

Are there comprehensive and accurate sources where I can get x86 CPUID feature flags (leafs 1, 7, and 0x80000001) for Intel and AMD processors sorted in chronological order of their introduction?

Answer (score 0):

A robust, but not very efficient, way to do this is to go through the released "IA-32 Intel® Architecture Software Developer’s Manual Documentation Changes" and look at whatever features got added to the CPUID instruction in that particular document which has a year/month associated with it on the first page.

You can find most of those documents here: http://kib.kiev.ua/x86docs/SDMs/

Documentation Changes PDFs match the following file pattern: 252046-*.pdf